# Can't Mock interface method when parameter is MultipartFormDataStreamProvider

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq

I have this weird problem when trying to mock an interface with MockedClass.Setup(x => x.Method()).

This is the interface I'm mocking.

```
public interface IClassFactory
{
    object GetValueFromFormData(string key, MultipartFormDataStreamProvider provider);
}
```

This is my test.

```
    [TestMethod]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(NullReferenceException))]
    public async Task ClassApiController_ImportClassList_ThrowsNullReferenceExceptionWhenNoClassId()
    {
        // Arrange
        _classFactory = new Mock<IClassFactory>();

        // THIS IS THE LINE THAT GIVES AN EXCEPTION
        _classFactory.Setup(x => x.GetValueFromFormData("classIdNull", null)).Returns(string.Empty);
        ClassApiController controller = new ClassApiController(_classRepository.Object, _surveyRepository.Object, _classFactory.Object);

        // Act
        string result = await controller.ImportClassList();
    }
```

If you look at my comment "THIS IS THE LINE THAT GIVES AN EXCEPTION" you see I send null, but it doesn't matter if I send the `MultipartFormDataStreamProvider` as an instansiated class instead, I still get the same exception.

```
Exception message: System.ArgumentException: Expression of type 'System.Net.Http.MultipartFormDataStreamProvider' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Net.Http.MultipartFormDataStreamProvider' of method 'System.Object GetValueFromFormData(System.String, System.Net.Http.MultipartFormDataStreamProvider)'
```

If you know why I can't mock the method just because it has this object as parameter, please help me, I'm clueless.

Thanks!

EDIT:
See solution in my answer

Comment: did you try changing the type to `IMultipartStreamProvider` in the `GetValueFromFormData` method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of @Vignesh.N I finally solved it. The simple answer in this case was that my solution is divided into several projects. Web, Test, Data and so on. In the web project I had referenced the web api .dll:s via Nuget and in the test project I had referenced them directly via `Add references -> Assemblies -> Framework`. Thereby the .dll:s had identical Versions but not File versions. After making Nuget take care of all the projects web api .dll files it worked instantly.

So all in all, stupid mistake and hard to spot.

Answer (score 1):

you should try

```
        _classFactory = Mock.Of<IClassFactory>();

        Mock.Get(_classFactory).Setup(x => x.GetValueFromFormData("classIdNull", It.IsAny<MultipartStreamProvider>()))
                     .Returns(string.Empty);
```

Comment: Hi, is _classFactory IClassFactory or something else? Because you cannot do .Setup directly on the interface...

Comment: Thanks, next question :) IMultipartStreamProvider, where do you get that interface from? As I see it MultipartFormDataStreamProvider inherits from an abstract class in the end?

Comment: sorry..that interface is not available in that case change to `It.IsAny<MultipartStreamProvider>()`

Comment: Unfortunately It.IsAny<MultipartStreamProvider>() doesn't work unless I change the interface parameters and do casting to ´MultipartFormDataStreamProvider´, which I'd rather not do :/

Comment: the thing is MultipartFormDataStreamProvider does not have any parameterless constructor; so it might not be able to Mock that type. you are better for changing the Interface method signature if nothing else works or try creating a mock object of `MultiparFormDataStreamProvider` yourself for testing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66453/discussion-between-andreas-and-vignesh-n).